# How can I remove dead links in Darktable?

Tags: darktable

Because of moving or renaming directories the **paths to my photos changed**. How can I automatically **remove all dead links** so that the missing photos aren't displayed (marked with a skull) anymore?

[image: skulls]

Comment: Is deleting the database an acceptable solution, or do you have new rolls added which you don't want to delete?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about database management, not about taking photographs. There are more appropriate groups on SE to deal with managing databases.

Comment: You are of course right, but unfortunately as long as there is no darktable SE site (my question is darktable specific, not about databases) I think the question is most appropriate on this photography SE. If there arises a new darktable SE on Area 51 I'd like to transfer this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The darktable project includes a shell script called [`purge_non_existing_images.sh`](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/tools/purge_non_existing_images.sh) which will remove any entry pointing to a file which doesn't exist.

It requires an environment that will run a POSIX-compatible "`sh`" script; on Windows, this may require the installation of such a shell... on Linux, the script itself may or may not be installed along with darktable depending on how it was packaged. Some distributions may provide a "darktable-tools" or similar package for this purpose (there are several other interesting things in the "tools" directory).

Comment: The shell script was not included in the darktable packages of my linux distribution but running the script you linked to worked fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Snap package, line 9:

```
DBFILE=$HOME/.config/darktable/library.db
```

should be replaced with:

```
DBFILE=$HOME/snap/darktable/current/library.db
```

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, if I sort by "id" (top of the lighttable interface) the missing images tend to be clustered together, so you can select them all, then on the right in the "selected image[s]" panel, you can select "remove" to delete the images from the library.